# Grafana Pod is in Init Error state after adding an existing PVC

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

Installing grafana using helm [charts](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts), the deployment goes well and the grafana ui is up, needed to add an existence persistence volume, ran the below cmd:

```
helm install grafana grafana/grafana -n prometheus --set persistence.enabled=true --set persistence.existingClaim=grafana-pvc
```

The init container crashes, with the below logs:

```
kubectl logs grafana-847b88556f-gjr8b -n prometheus -c init-chown-data                    
chown: /var/lib/grafana: Operation not permitted
chown: /var/lib/grafana: Operation not permitted
```

On checking the deployment yaml found this section:

```
initContainers:
      - command:
        - chown
        - -R
        - 472:472
        - /var/lib/grafana
        image: busybox:1.31.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: init-chown-data
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: false
          runAsUser: 0
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana
          name: storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 472
        runAsGroup: 472
        runAsUser: 472
      serviceAccount: grafana
      serviceAccountName: grafana
```

Why is the operation failing though its running with `runAsUser: 0` ? and the pvc is having `access:ReadWriteMany`, any workaround ? Or am I missing something

Thanks !!

Comment: What does the underlying PVC/PV look like? Some providers don't support changing ownership of the root folder of the mount.

Comment: @coderanger I have setup k8s on VMs hosted on prem, PV is allocated on a NFS server which is the master k8s node itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFS turns on `root_squash` mode by default which functionally disables uid 0 on clients as a superuser (maps those requests to some other UID/GID, usually 65534). You can disable this in your mount options, or use something other than NFS. I would recommend the latter, NFS is bad.

Comment: Yes setting mount options to `no_root_squash` worked. Thanks, will plan to use some other methods.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, sometimes you might want to avoid changing your storage provider settings or it is impossible at all.

In my case, the error described in the question occured while deploying **kube-prometheus-stack** helm chart. I wasn't able to access storage provider settings, so I read through chart's example values, where I noticed following section:

```
initChownData:
  ## If false, data ownership will not be reset at startup
  ## This allows the prometheus-server to be run with an arbitrary user
  ##
  enabled: true
```

I changed `enabled` to false and after `helm upgrade ...` pod initialized successfully and with storage working as expected. This appears to be somewhat safer solution than changing storage provider's security policy and certainly requires less effort.